# Odoo POS javascript on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, odoo-8, point-of-sale

I'd like to perform an on change event on a `<select>` fields. Depending on the selected value I'd like to filter another `<select>` field. Now idea how I can achieve this, any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure What exactly you want

check the code snippet, this is from the understanding that i had from your problem statement

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var choose_one = document.getElementById("select_one");
  choose_one.addEventListener("change", ChangedOption);
}

function ChangedOption() {
  var choose_one = document.getElementById("select_one");
  var choose_two = document.getElementById("select_two");
  var selectedIndex = choose_one.selectedIndex;
  if (selectedIndex > -1) {
    var selectedValue = choose_one.options[choose_one.selectedIndex].value;
    var selectTwoOptions = choose_two.options;

    for (var i = 0; i < choose_two.options.length; i++)
      if (selectTwoOptions[i].value == selectedValue) {
        selectTwoOptions[i].selected = true;
      }
    
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="select_one">

  <option value="1">one</option>

  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<select id="select_two">
  <option value="4">four</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="5">five</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps